# Apply a displacement map to a mesh in the current Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ma791nd8/1/

I am having some issues with outdated tutorials and some lack of documentation so I thought I would ask here.

Having looked at one of their examples I made a jsfiddle and created a clone with the newer syntax. However, I am getting a cors issue eventhough I set up `myTexture.crossOrigin = ''` The next problem is I have no idea why this is not working in general. How come?

Here you can see a demo of the original example: https://github.com/meetar/three.js-displacement-map

My changes in the JSFiddle version:

```
    // scene setup
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // CAMERA

    var fov = 45; // camera field-of-view in degrees
    var width = renderer.domElement.width;
    var height = renderer.domElement.height;
    var aspect = width / height; // view aspect ratio
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, aspect );
    camera.position.z = -200;
    camera.position.y = -400;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    // LIGHTS
    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
    scene.add( ambientLight );
    // SHADERS
planeMesh = new THREE.Group();

var myTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
myTexture.crossOrigin = '';
myTexture.load('https://leveldev.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/heightmap.jpeg',
    function (myTexture) {
    var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
    var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );
    uniforms[ "enableDisplacement" ].value = true;
    uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ].value = true;
    uniforms[ "tDisplacement" ].value = myTexture;
    uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = myTexture;
    uniforms[ "uDisplacementScale" ].value = 50;
    var parameters = { fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader, vertexShader: shader.vertexShader, uniforms: uniforms, lights: true, wireframe: true };
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( parameters );

    var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
        planeMesh.add(plane)
    }
);

    planeMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
    scene.add(planeMesh);
    // FUNCTIONS

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
```

Comment: Consider using `MeshPhongMaterial`, which supports displacement maps: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_displacementmap.html

Comment: @WestLangley I will look at it now. Meanwhile, I would appreciate if you could show a minimal jsfiddle showing how that works with only displacement. Would be a bit more stripped down and easy to visualize. Ofcourse only if you want to : )

Comment: @WestLangley here it never mentions displacement maps as a parameter http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshPhongMaterial

Comment: @WestLangley it only gets as far as bump and normal maps but thats it. So I am pretty suprised that the example works that you showed me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest `MeshPhongMaterial` got displacement maps built-in, see this simple example for Three.js r73:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var myDisplacementMap = loader.load( 'somePath/someImage.jpg' );

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    //...
    displacementMap: myDisplacementMap,
    displacementScale: 10
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmn7z00b/